# Adding an external server in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, apache, windows-xp, aptana

How can I add an external server in Aptana Studio 3, since there is no Servers view?

[Here](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Configuring_Aptana_Studio_to_use_an_external_web_server) [are](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Setting_up_an_external_web_server_to_preview_PHP_and_other_non-HTML_pages) some instructions on how to do it but they both use Windows > Show view > Servers which is no longer available in Aptana 3. With the console is possible? How?

I have a wamp server installed and I can run correctly php files stored inside the htdocs folder. Now I want to run those php files from Aptana but I was getting blank pages.

In Project > Run Configurations I noticed the "Use selected server" option but no possibilty to add a server there, so I used "Use base URL" together with "Append project name" and now I can run php files from Aptana but I am still wondering if it is the best option and how I could tell Aptana to use the wamp server.

[image: adding a server in Aptana Studio 3]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Aptana Studio 3 you need to open Preferences, Aptana/ Web Servers node and add your local apache server there.
If you set the document root correctly, your apache server will be used for previewing in Studio (See Preview button on toolbar).

Comment: Document Root should be the htdocs folder, right? And base url http://localhost/? I have these but the Preview button is disabled

Comment: Correct for both. Your project should be located at the htdocs too so local path to server URL will work correctly. What kind of files you previewing ? It should work fine as-is for HTML, but PHP will require a fix. In the mean time you have to add *.php association into Preferences/General/Content Types/HTML. And you should still use "PHP Source Editor" (see Open With).

Comment: You are right, html files had preview enabled and an association was needed for the php files. Previewing *.php off-hand doesn't work (html is ok) but it does run if specifying the full url in the preview window. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an alias in my apache config like

```
Alias /aptana "C:/Aptana/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace"
```

where I have MyApp project in Aptana,

Then  in Run cnfiguration, Web Browser, My Apache Server,

```
Use base url = http://<domain><port>/aptana/
```

In my browser URL : http:///aptana/MyApp

That's all

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following method:

1.find the httpd.conf in {path to Apache}/conf/, set the "DocumentRoot" value as your 
Aptana workspace.

2.Run->Run Configurations.. choose a web browser, set the "Use base URL" value as http://`localhost`/{here is your project name}/

3.run.