# PHP not showing up in browser Aptana Studio

Tags: php, aptana

I just installed Aptana Studio 3 and I'm testing out PHP. I tested to see if php worked by using phpinfo(), but nothing shows up on the web browser. I configured the preview settings by right clicking the project folder and going to properties, but that still doesn't work. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the php server may not be specified, try opening preferences to specify your server.

If need more instructions , try this thread [Adding an external server in Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968156/adding-an-external-server-in-aptana-studio-3).