# Aptana 3 Are Spaces Allowed In PHP Project Names Using WAMP As Preview Server?

Tags: php, wamp, aptana, wampserver

Using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805 I have followed [this guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Setting+up+an+external+web+server+to+preview+PHP+and+other+non-HTML+pages) and set up a few projects (using PHP) I am working on with WAMP. I am previewing the php files in the projects with WAMP as preview server and that works just fine.

Though whenever I have a space in the project name I cannot seem to set the preview server to WAMP and Aptana automatically chooses to use the built-in server rendering the preview of PHP files useless.

It is possible at all to still have space in the project names when working with PHP files, WAMP and Aptana?

If so how would I be able to insert such spaces for the Base URL, Document Root and Project name in Aptana please?

Does this have to do with WAMP not liking spaces in paths, though is there a way to make it accept spaces perhaps? Are all PHP project names without spaces always?

Thankful for any help or info given about this.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the Document Root for the Apache server to be my Aptana Workspace. This allowed me to keep the old project names (and the old workspace location) with spaces as well as seeing all projects under `http://localhost/(project name)` including spaces in the project name in the URL, in Aptana preview as well as in any browser.

1. Find http.conf, for WAMP default install this is `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf`
2. Edit line `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"` to `DocumentRoot "d:/web work/anything/aptana workspace/"` or where ever your Aptana Workspace is.
3. Edit line `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">` to `<Directory "d:/web work/anything/aptana workspace/">` or where ever your Aptana Workspace is. Should be the same as Document Root.
4. Restart WAMP server. Click green icon and select Restart All Services.
5. In Aptana go to Window -> Preferences -> type "server" in the blue marked search box saying "type filter text" and select `Web Server`.
6. In Web Server add and New server with following settings: Name: WAMP (or whatever you like), Base URL: `http://localhost/` and Document Root: `d:\web work\anything\aptana workspace\` or where ever your Aptana workspace is.

Done. Like this I have the workspace separate from the server root, I can preview PHP files and projects with spaces in the project name from inside Aptana as well as local browsers and there is no fear of having files or projects deleted when changing WAMP server settings.

edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20866248/1010918) helped me finding the solution.