# Aptana server currently unavailable

Tags: python, aptana, aptana3

I am a complete newbie to all of this so please be gentle. I am trying to learn python and have started to follow exercises from Lynda.com. The video I am watching suggests to download Aptana Studio 3.6.1 to use with Python. I have downloaded and installed it however upon opening the Aptana Studio start page keeps coming up with the following error:

> Server Currently Unavailable.

I have been trying to find a solution but have had no such luck. I am hoping one of you might be able to help.

Just a reminder I am completely new to this so please explain everystep as simply as possible. 
Thank you for any help or advice you can give me.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968156/adding-an-external-server-in-aptana-studio-3

Comment: Same experience here - the start page for Aptana looks like it is navigating to http://content.aptana.com/aptana/my_aptana/?content=start
That URL is no longer available (probably because it was removed by Aptana), which is causing the Server Currently Unavailable error.