# server currently unavailable on aptana?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I have installed Aptana Studio 3 to make a RoR project by following this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0joa5MNNRJU&t=633s. I really did the same but when I open Aptana Studio 3, I get a `server currently unavailable` message instead of the nice menu. I have already glanced at [Adding an external server in Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968156/adding-an-external-server-in-aptana-studio-3) but I didn't catch it as it doesn't seem to me to be the same problem. Could someone help ? Thanks [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbHWe.png)